# Passing arguments to hive query

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I am trying to pass command line arguments through the below ,but its not working . Can anybody help me with what I am doing wrong here!

```
hive -f test2.hql -hiveconf partition=20170117 -hiveconf -hiveconf datepartition=20170120
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your arguments before the query file,

```
hive --hiveconf partition='20170117' --hiveconf datepartition='20170120' -f test2.hql
```

And use them in your queries in `test2.hql` like this,

```
${hiveconf:partition}
```

**Example:**

```
select * from tablename where partition=${hiveconf:partition} and date=${hiveconf:datepartition}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives:

1) if using hive command line, you can just elaborate the whole sql command and execute it like:

```
hive -e <command>
```

and explicit the parameters as literals.

2) if using beeline (preferred to hive), just append this to the command line:

```
--hivevar myparam='myvalue'
```